# Save a file/stream to local folder from Response Output stream?

Tags: asp.net, file, client, save, response

I have an excel file in my Response Output stream. I can Open the stream as a file after a prompt, but it doesn't seem I can save it directly to a specified folder on my client. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, you cannot specify where the file is going to be downloaded by the browser. That is controlled by the user.